# How do I remove all reference outlets from a view at once?

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, iboutlet

I'm relatively new to `iOS` development and I'm looking for ways to speed up when programming at XCode.

*I know it's possible to remove an outlet by right clicking to a view in the storyboard and then click the little x by the referencing outlet.*

Is there a keyboard shortcut or another way to remove **all outlet references from a view at once**?

This would be very useful when copying and pasting views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By clicking on View Controller it will show on the right side all connected interface outlets, and it's easier to remove one by one there. This is not what you looking for, but at least will help to remove outlet references a bit faster.

[image]

Comment: Same is true for ctrl or right-clicking the view controller (or view or whatever you want).