# How can I delete a UIImage with its outlet?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I click and delete a UIImage by cmd + del it deletes the UIImage on the Main (Base) but in the ViewController I can still see the outlet that I have created for that specific UIImage. Is there a way to delete both the outlet and the UIImage at the same time?

Comment: No there is no way to do that but here is a helpful post regarding the same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472469/how-do-i-remove-all-reference-outlets-from-a-view-at-once